# Check 2 strings without case sensitivity or use equalsIgnoreCase method

Tags: java, string, hashmap, switch-statement, equals

I have some inputted String `String usrInput;` that user could import some string once into App without any case-sensitivity policy like: "start","Start","START","end" ,"END" and etc.

And I have a Map that i inserted my strings for example "start" into that and put it into `HashMap<String, String> myMap`:

```java
Map<String, String> listOfActions = new HashMap<>();
listOfActions.put(myStr, myStr);
```

Now I want to check `listOfActions` members to get for example "start" filed in every case model ("start","Start","START") , currently I do like below:

```java
if (listOfActions.containsKey(usrInput.toUpperCase())
        || listOfActions.containsKey(usrInput.toLowerCase())) {
    /// some do
}
```

So I want to know:

**1.** Is there any way to get String value without case-sensitivity?
I will also add this here I couldn't use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method for get items from `Map` because its return `Boolean`.

**2.** I have similar problem in switch-case statements to check 2 string equality without case-sensitivity.

Comment: Just agree upon what case you want to convert to, e.g. store it a `start` in the map / as a case value and then when you have a `String` to check always call `toLowerCase` first.

Comment: Well, the question isn't quite clear.
Why have you put the same values? listOfActions.put(myStr, myStr);
Why you couldn't use equalsIgnoreCase? Why you've got troubles with switch-case? Could you please provide more code snippets.
It sounds to me that you do extra effort working on ordinary task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Map<String, String> listOfActions = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Other solutions can be Apache's CaseInsensitiveMap or Spring's LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.

Please see https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-with-case-insensitive-keys for more details about these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use inputs as map keys (i.e. you don't need to later reproduce the strings in original casing), I suggest just lowercasing all inputs before inserting them into the map:

```
Map<String, String> listOfActions = new HashMap<>();
listOfActions.put(myStr.toLowerCase(), myStr);
```

This will simplify locating the values later on, since you know that all keys are already lowercased, so the lookup becomes easy:

```
if (listOfActions.containsKey(myStr.toLowerCase())) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: i edited my question please read it again . thank you

Comment: I don't see anything in the updated version of your question that would invalidate my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance of `HashMap`, you can *override* some of its methods, such as `put` and `containsKey` like this:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>() {
    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return super.containsKey(key.toString().toLowerCase());
    }
};

map.put("START", "doStart");

System.out.println(map); // {start=doStart}

System.out.println(map.containsKey("START")); // true
System.out.println(map.containsKey("Start")); // true
System.out.println(map.containsKey("start")); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is make everything upper-case or lower-case, then compare them.

```
string.toLowerCase().equals("other string");
string.toUpperCase().equals("OTHERSTRING");
```

This way, whether it is lower-case or upper-case, it will only be compared as one or the other, and acts as though it were case insensitive.